# How to run a web application ,like as we do in windows form application by clicking .exe file inside bin folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I need a way to run web application , like as we do for windows form application by clicking .exe file from bin folder.

Example:if windows form application namely "helloworld" is created means, we can move to the actual folder where the project is stored and we can run the application manually by moving into helloworld folder->bin folder->debug folder-> helloworld.exe.

Likewise i need a way to run wed based applications.I am using C# language in Visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1):

you run web applications by publishing them to a web server and then opening a link in browser. your options are:

1. open project in visual studio and hit F5 to start debugging. visual studio will launch a built-in webserver to host your application. while it's running you will be able to access it via url similar to `http://localhost:53212/appurl`
2. if you have IIS installed you can publish project to your IIS. you would be able to access application even without visual studio via url similar to `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/myapp` depending on settings
3. you may choose web hosting provider and publish your web app to a server. you will be able to access your app via url like `http://myaccount.hostingcompany.com/` or if you buy a domain than via `http://yourowndomain.com`

if you need an icon so that users could double click on it and go to your web app url, create a text file that contains

```
 [InternetShortcut]
 URL=http://www.yourdomainurl.com/ 
 IconFile=
 IconIndex=0
```

and store it as Yourname.url file.

however if you need an executable that behaves similarly to a web page, you can host a webbrowser object in your windows application or create WPF application.

Answer (score 0):

For a web application you have to host in on IIS(web server).

Here is a link that will help you [get started with IIS](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article1247-how-to-host-aspnet-application-on-the-web-server-iis.aspx)

Web applications need a web server, and running is not as simple as clicking an exe.

.net does allow you to create [installers for web applicaitons](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MicrosoftWebApplicationInstallerOpenSourceWebAppsDeliveredAndInstalled.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you could create a windows form project and add a web browser control with the URL you want it pointed to.

You could also run it without IIS (from command line) or mount it as a windows service.

http://www.realsoftwareblog.com/2012/03/running-standalone-web-application-as.html